# BETWEEN two dates in an Access database using SQL

Tags: sql

Me again, sorry.

Trying to get all the data between two dates in my Access Database. The data type for the column is "Date/Time" which I believe is correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM SaleProperty
WHERE MarketDate BETWEEN '01/05/2013' AND '30/06/2013';
```

When I use this, I am told that there is a data mismatch and the query does not work. Sorry again for what is probably a very basic question but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Cheers again!

Answer (score 1):

Access (Jet) uses `#` to identify a date literal.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SaleProperty
WHERE MarketDate BETWEEN #01/05/2013# AND #30/06/2013#;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of looking for things which only Access does when it comes to dates. Thank you!